# Hermite polynomials as a basis for generating function

Tags: generating-functions, hermite-polynomials

I am embedding a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in a generating function using Hermite polynomials:

\begin{align}
\{a_n\} \mapsto f_{\{a_n\}}(x)=\sum_n H_n(x)a_n
\end{align}

I would like to find an inverse transformation from $f_{\{a_n\}}(x)$ to a given $a_k$.

The only thing that I came up with so far is to use the orthogonality of Hermite polynomials, so that

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{H_k(x)e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}2^k k!}f_{\{a_n\}}(x)dx = a_k
\end{align}

However, integrals introduce issues in other parts of my project and I would like to avoid them. Are there simpler alternatives (for instance a differential operator)?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have a sequence $\,\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty.\,$
Define a function $\,f(x)\,$ by
$$ f(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n(x)\,a_n \tag{1} $$
assuming that $\,f(x)\,$ is convergent and analytic at $0$.
The given question asks

> I would like to find an inverse transformation from $f_{\{a_n\}}(x)$ to a given $a_k$.

We need to express $\,x^n\,$ as a linear combination of Hermite
polynomials. The [OEIS sequence A067147](https://oeis.org/A067147)
solves that problem. Accordingly, define the function

$\, A(n,k) := n!/(k!\,((n-k)/2)!\,2^n) \,$ if $n\ge 0,\;
 k\le n,\,$ and $n-k$ is even.
Otherwise, $\,A(n,k)=0.$

This function has the desired property that
$$ x^n = \sum_{k=0}^n H(k)\,A(n,k). \tag{2} $$
Get the power series coefficients of $\,f(x)\,$ using
$$ b_n :=(d^n f(x)/dx^n)/n!, \qquad f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\,x^n. \tag{3}$$
Finally we get the
$$ a_k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A(n,k)\,b_n. \tag{4} $$
The exponential generating function of $\,A(n,k)\,$
gives the ordinary generating function of $\,\{a_n\}$
$$ g(y) := \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\,y^k =
 \exp(\,y\, \mathcal{D}+ \mathcal{D}^2)[f(x)] \tag{5} $$
where the differential operator $\,\mathcal{D}\,$ is
$$ \mathcal{D}[f(x)]:=\frac12 \frac{df(x)}{dx}. \tag{6} $$